# Handling segmentation fault due to a C++ subprocess spawned by Python code

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, child-process, segmentation-fault, signal-handling

I have read a few articles about signal handling in Python, and for some reason am not getting the desired output.
This is my C++ code. It is meant to simulate a segmentation fault.
The purpose of the Python code is to run the C++ program as a subprocess and to catch run time errors, if any.

```
int main()
{
int*a;
a=NULL;
cout<<*a<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

The python code is as follows:

```
from subprocess import *
import signal

def handler(signum,frame):
    print "Error Occured",signum
    raise IOError("Segmentation Fault Occured.")

#The C++ code is already compiled

a = Popen(["./a.out"])
try:
    signal.signal(signal.SIGSEGV,handler)  
except IOError as e:
    print e
```

When the C++ code is run on the terminal directly, (not using the Python code) this is the output:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When the same is run using the Python code, no output is observed.
What is going wrong in my approach?
Thanking you in advance.

PS: I tried this as an alternative and it worked. However, it cannot be used for my application since I cannot use wait() method.

```
a.wait()
if a.returncode == -11:
    print "Segmentation fault, core dumped"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the issue was solved. Instead of using

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGSEGV,handler)
```

I used the following:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD,handler)
```